# how to update a table between two databases

Tags: mysql, kettle

I need yo update two tables from different database
lets consider animal table in database1 and same animal table in database2.if the data is inserted or deleted in database1 animal table its need to be get affected concurrently in database2 animal table.i tried using kettle for this but it get look entire records any other way to do efficiently.I am using mysql database.

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.6, definitely have a look at: http://intuitive-search.blogspot.com/2011/07/binary-log-api-and-replication-listener.html
They added support for binary log streaming which will achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could create [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for `INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE` on `database1.table1` that will change `database2.animal`.

To access database2.animal you do:

```
insert into database2.animal values( ... );

update database2.animal SET (...);

delete from database2.animal WHERE (...);
```

You just have to put the database name before the table name and you get access to it.